# How to fix null object reference Location

Tags: java, android

I am having a problem with my application when trying to take my location in the onMapReady method.

I tried to take the latitude and longitude in different variables but it still comes to the onMapReady method as null.

In the Toast within the getLastLocation method it shows me my real location but when I use myLocation outside the resulting coordinates are 0.0 -0.0

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

Location myLocation = null;
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocation;
private static final int Request_Code = 101;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}

private void getLastLocation() {
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, Request_Code);
    }
    Task<Location> task = fusedLocation.getLastLocation();
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if(location != null) {
                myLocation = location;
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), myLocation.getLatitude() + "" + myLocation.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // This correctly shows me my true location
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);
    fusedLocation = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
    getLastLocation();
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync( this);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Request_Code:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getLastLocation();
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    if (googleMap != null) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Estas aquí");
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 6));
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    }
 }
}
```

ERROR LOG:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mint, PID: 11019
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.mint.MapFragment.onMapReady(MapFragment.java:81)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzak.zza(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:12)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source:12)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:667)
    at ck.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19629065@19.6.29 (100400-0):14)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bb.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19629065@19.6.29 (100400-0):4)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bi.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19629065@19.6.29 (100400-0):2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at ln.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19629065@19.6.29 (100400-0):5)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6672)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11019 SIG: 9
Process 11019 terminated.
```

Comment: If getLastLocation() (specifically onSuccess()) is not called before onMapReady() then myLocation is not initialized, and will remain null. You try to get lat and long from it here :  LatLng latLng = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());

Comment: This error is giving you a hint [java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference]

Answer (score 0):

your code is throwing nullPointerException because myLocation is still null so try to use below code

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

Location myLocation = null;
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocation;
private static final int Request_Code = 101;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}

private void getLastLocation() {
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, Request_Code);
    }
    Task<Location> task = fusedLocation.getLastLocation();
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if(location != null) {
                myLocation = location;

                //change was made here
                SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                mapFragment.getMapAsync( this);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), myLocation.getLatitude() + "" + myLocation.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // This correctly shows me my true location
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);
    fusedLocation = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
    getLastLocation();
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Request_Code:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getLastLocation();
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    if (googleMap != null) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Estas aquí");
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 6));
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    }
 }
}
```